# Javascript return certain string from body

Tags: javascript

i am totally new to Javascript so after some help

```
if (BODY.length && BODY[0]["id"]) {
    result = {
        "EmpID": BODY,
        "Status": "User found",
        "Code": 200
    };
} else {
    result = {
    "Status": "User not found",
    "Code": 404
    };
}
```

I have the above script which pulls data from a response body and i get a return of

```
{
    "EmpID": [
        {
            "id": "1EF7C992-CBC1-45AF-83CC-304044E8284B"
        }
    ],
    "Status": "User found",
    "Code": 200
}
```

the id changes depending on the user but i just need the EmpID to be

"EmpID":  1EF7C992-CBC1-45AF-83CC-304044E8284B or whatever the code is returned without the { } and "id":

e.g

```
{
    "EmpID": 1EF7C992-CBC1-45AF-83CC-304044E8284B
    "Status": "User found",
    "Code": 200
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different things, which one are you using?

Comment: Javascript according to the program i have using

Comment: You have to parse the array of objects `"EmpID": [
        {
            "id": "1EF7C992-CBC1-45AF-83CC-304044E8284B"
        }
    ]` I would parse the entire json into an object using `JSON.parse()` and grab the id from the `array[i].id`

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the ID from the correct location in your return statement just like you do when you check it exists in your if statement e.g.

```
result = {
    "EmpID": BODY[0]["id"],
    "Status": "User found",
    "Code": 200
};
```

Comment: @chazsolo according to the question it is.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the response you get.

```
{
    "EmpID": [
        {
            "id": "1EF7C992-CBC1-45AF-83CC-304044E8284B"
        }
    ],
    "Status": "User found",
    "Code": 200
}
```

then you can return

```
{
"EmpID": response["EmpID"][0].id,
"Status": "User found",
 "Code": 200
}
```